# Xlwings is not writing the correct formula to excel causing an error in the value

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to write a script using Xlwings and I have a formula that I need to insert into a column. I wrote a string that represents the formula and is correct because when I print the string and enter it into excel the formula works. However when I call it in xlwings using:

```
formulaColumnN = "= IF(INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)-1)=\"TAPA\",INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!M:M,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)-1),INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!M:M,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)))"
sheet3.range("N2").formula = formulaColumnN
```

it does not work in fact when I look at what is in the cell I get this:

```
=@ IF(@INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,@'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)-1)="TAPA",INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!M:M,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,@'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)-1),INDEX('ZOR-ZCCK'!M:M,MATCH(E2&F2&H2&I2,@'ZOR-ZCCK'!E:E&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!F:F&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!H:H&@'ZOR-ZCCK'!I:I,0)))
```

I have no clue why the @ symbol is added and if I delete them the formula works. Please let me know if anyone knows why this is happening it has never done this on any other formula in xlwings.

Also conversely if someone knows how to convert this formula in Pandas because I tried but have been struggling to figure it out.

Comment: Works OK for me, no extraneous characters added and the string in the cell matches your formula (minus the delimiter characters). Of course I cannot say if the formula works but Excel does treat as being a formula. Not that I believe it might be affecting, but is their a reason there is a space between the '=' and rest of the formula? You can try just writing as text to the cell; **sheet3.range("N2").value**

Comment: No there was no reason I was just fiddling around with it to see if it would change anything. So you're saying it is working for you, I have been so annoyed with this because I could not see why it was not working maybe ill try it in a new notebook and see if anything changes. Also I believe if I were to use .value then it wouldn't work because the value is different from a formula I believe

Comment: A formula is just a line of text, entering '=SUM(A1+B2)' isn't any different than typing 'hello' in a cell it's just how Excel then interprets it. Try using '.value', what do you have to have to loose? If it helps, I tried both and the same characters were entered in the cell for each.

Comment: Sadly I am getting the same error, I still see the @ symbols showing up which for some reason are being added and they are making the formula unable to work

Comment: I'm more on the python side than Excel so don't have any ideas on your complex formula. Notwithstanding pasting the formula works, I have to assume Excel is adding the @ in an attempt to 'fix' the formula based on the referenced data. I can't duplicate your sheet/data the formula references but Excel will add '@' for data referenced from tables and maybe other reasons. Have you researched reasons Excel adds '@' to a formula to see if any of these might apply? This may be why it works for me since I'm just testing on a blank sheet. You could also try testing on a blank sheet to confirm.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get it working through pandas bu just making a function, I am still unsure why the issue happened and it has never happened in xlwings previously so hopefully it was a one off, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you instead use `sheet3.range("N3").formula2 =`  then you shouldn't have the problem (instead of just `.formula`.

I haven't looked into the differences extensively, I just know that this solves the problem, but the explanation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2) if you want to read about it.